# Convolutional layer return the same result for different input

Tags: python, keras

i'm using a neural network on DNA sequences for classification, where the input is encoded in one hot encoding.

I was starting using a very simple network, just for some test.

```
ishape = (None,4)
ksize = 18

model.add(Conv1D(16, ksize, activation='relu', input_shape=ishape))
model.add(GlobalAvgPool1D(data_format="channels_last"))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
```

The problem was that it returns ever the same results, that change every time that i train the networks.

So i try to see the output of the global averaging layer.. and what i found is that the output is almost the same, for example, considering only one value, it goes from 0.17484 to 0.17424. ( This happend also if i try to predict a fake input with all 0 or all 1)

I don't know how resolve it.. some suggestion?

P.S. this problem is indipendent by the training, because i found that it's the same if i try to predict the input after the initializzation but before the training.

UPDATE---

I found that the weight of the convooutional layer are small, in the range of 0.1 or 0.01.. considering that i work with only 0 and 1 value, is possible that this is the problem? How can i fix this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your model in https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qPJ0pWXUzZx2N8tWpBmdSUNQSEPWl5lT?usp=sharing. I don't see a problem with the output values being the same. btw: do you want to predict 2 independent conditions ? or 2 mutually exclusive classes. If it is the later use 'softmax' as the activation function of the output layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I'm a noob in neural networks.. so i just assume that it was a problem. Reading something more i find that initially the weight are really small and i'm starting to think that this is the reason for the similar output values. Instead, answering your second question, i want to predict 2 exclusive classes, i find somewhere that sigmoid is for binary classification, softmax is used for more than 2 classes.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is expected behaviour from keras/tensorflow. Same code can give you different results because of randomness that is present during model fit and training..

May be you can try this  and import below line on the top of your code

```
from numpy.random import seed
seed(1)
from tensorflow import set_random_seed
set_random_seed(2)
```

for reference you can check on this [url](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reproducible-results-neural-networks-keras/) and it's totally fine to have this kind of results

Comment: I think that i misspoke... the problem is the exact opposite: if after ( or before) the training i use the model to predict N values, i will get N output that are the same. 

I think that for some reasons the network return an output based only on the weight and not the input